# How to create local DHCP server to give addresses to bridge ports?

Tags: dhcp, network-bridge, dnsmasq

How to create and setup local DHCP server(dnsmasq) via terminal to give addresses to bridge ports? For example I have bridge br0 and need to give some address to tap interface that connected to br0. How it can be done? Thanks very much.

Comment: Look at hte Ubuntu Docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server

Comment: I tried to use isc-dhcp-server but stuck with this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1448657). Trying to do it with dnsmasq.